# SQL join and populate new table with a new column and values based on other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case

I am trying some practice SQL problems and I am having trouble with one question.

The question wants me to return a table that has [Test ID, Test Name, and Test Difficulty]. The issue is that I have to create the [Test Difficulty] column based on data between two tables (participant scores are in table A and test name is in table B). The tables share test id.

In short, I need to join the two tables, then average scores, and then create the new test difficulty column and populate it based on the average scores (e.g., if average score is less than 20, then test difficulty = "hard").

Currently, I have managed to join the tables and average the scores but I am having trouble with the last part of creating this new column and populating based on the conditional. Can anyone help?

*Note, creating new table is not an option, all should be done through the query execution area.*

Code below:

Table A

```
create table reports (
  id integer not null,
  task_id integer not null,
  candidate varchar(40) not null,
  score integer not null,
  unique(id)
 )
```

Table B

```
create table tasks (
    id integer not null,
  name varchar(40) not null,
  unique(id)
)
```

Values in each table

```
insert into reports values (13, 101, 'John Smith', 100);
insert into reports values (24, 123, 'Delaney Lloyd', 34);
insert into reports values (37, 300, 'Monroe Jimenez', 50);
insert into reports values (49, 101, 'Stanley Price', 45);
insert into reports values (51, 142, 'Tanner Sears', 37);
insert into reports values (68, 142, 'Lara Fraser', 3);
insert into reports values (83, 300, 'Tanner Sears', 0);

insert into tasks values (101, 'MinDist');
insert into tasks values (123, 'Equi');
insert into tasks values (142, 'Median');
insert into tasks values (300, 'Tricoloring');
```

My code:

```
select * 
from
(
select reports.task_id, 
tasks.name,
avg(reports.score) as average
from reports
join tasks
on tasks.id = reports.task_id
group by reports.task_id, tasks.name
) practice;
```

Comment: Include the results you are expecting to see please.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. We need to know whether you want to create a new table or not. Just to clarify for you: a SELECT statement can include "additional" columns based on expressions (i.e. a calculation based on other columns) It sounds like this is what you are after - i.e. you do not need to create a table to get the data you want, you can just write a select query that produces it. I think you've already done it though, so what's that actual question that you have? Adding expected output will help you understand your issue as well as us

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! They were very helpful and I will keep them in mind for future questions. @D.Tabakov answered my question perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear whether you want to insert your results somewhere, but here's something that's as close to the query you have as you can get:

```
select
    practice.*,
    case
        when practice.average <= 20 then 'HARD'
        when practice.average > 20 and practice.average <= 40 then 'MEDIUM'
        else 'EASY'
    end as test_difficulty
from (
    select
        reports.task_id, 
        tasks.name,
        avg(reports.score) as average
    from reports
    join tasks on tasks.id = reports.task_id
    group by reports.task_id, tasks.name
) practice;
```

You can, of course, alter the CASE statement as needed. I'm using "practice.average > 20 and practice.average <= 40" instead of BETWEEN, because BETWEEN is inclusive; this way each difficulty starts on .0(...)01 and ends on 0.

There are of course many other ways to do it - CTEs, functions, etc. - but this seems closest to what you're describing.